# Ошибка при установке модуля python

Tags: python, установка, модули

такая вот проблема у меня.При попытке установки модуля numexpr через прописание команды в терминале PyCharm pip instal numexpr,вылезают вот такие сообщения.Подскажите,почему не устанавливается модуль?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Надеюсь,теперь нормально?

Comment: Добавьте ошибку текстом вместо скриншота.

Answer (score 0):

По моему он жалуется на отсутствие компилятора для C++. Попробуйте установить Visual Studio Build Tools для C++, возможно решит проблему.